# How do you manipulate selected text via a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I'm working on a **Firefox extension** that will manipulate highlighted text.

On a stand-alone page, I can get the selected text with:

```
selectedText = document.selection?document.selection.createRange().text;
```

Then I'd manipulate the selected text with string operations on the textarea in question.  Unfortunately, that isn't possible for a plugin since I don't know where the user's selected text is.

Is there a way get the name of the element in which text is selected or to alter selected text without the name of the element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
selectedText = content.getSelection().toString();
```

Comment: and to prove yourself in a dumb-simple way, open some random webpage in Firefox, select some text on that page, focus address-bar, paste "javascript:void(alert(content.getSelection()))" (without quotes), and press Enter.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the range object from your user selection:

```
var userSelection;
if (window.getSelection)
    userSelection = window.getSelection();
else if (document.selection)    // should come last; Opera!
    userSelection = document.selection.createRange();

var rangeObject = getRangeObject(userSelection);
```

...

```
function getRangeObject(selectionObject) {
    if (selectionObject.getRangeAt)
        return selectionObject.getRangeAt(0);
    else { // Safari!
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(selectionObject.anchorNode, selectionObject.anchorOffset);
        range.setEnd(selectionObject.focusNode, selectionObject.focusOffset);
        return range;
    }
}

...
```

The Range object has start and end container nodes, etc ..

more information can be found on Quirksmode [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html) and on w3.org [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I tried putting those functions into my overlay.js, but couldn't manage to alert() out any highlighted text after installing the plugin.

I'm a bit of a novice here, but is it possible that putting Safari and Opera code into a Firefox extension is the problem?