# Firefox extension getSelection().toString() not getting the selected text

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, selection, browser-extension

I'm making a basic Firefox extension, which takes the selected text on a page, puts it into an URL and opens it in a new tab. I'm struggling with taking the selected text.

I'm aware of the Firefox bug in textarea and input, however, I'm testing it on regular page text.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Send2search test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["menus"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["bg.js"]
  },
}
```

bg.js:

```
browser.menus.create(
    {
      id: "gglSearch",
      title: "Search in new tab.",
      contexts: ["selection"],
    },
  );

browser.menus.onClicked.addListener(async function (info, tab) {
    var selectedTxt = window.getSelection().toString();
    if (info.menuItemId == "gglSearch") {
        var searchUrl = `https://www.google.com/search?q=${selectedTxt}`;
        let openNewTab = browser.tabs.create(
            {
                active: false,
                url: searchUrl,
                index: tab.index+1
            }
        );
    };
});
```

Every time it just opens blank google search, so nothing is saved in the selectedTxt variable. What am I doing wrong?

I also tried content.getSelection().toString() instead (https://stackoverflow.com/a/670258/20367262), but that caused the new tab to not get created at all.

PS: I know Firefox has "Search Google for" on right click by default, I'm just trying to work out extension developing basics on this.

Comment: You've to get the selection from the target page, not from the extension window.

Comment: How do I refer to the target page? What's the variable for that?

Comment: Replace the: 

    var selectedTxt = window.getSelection().toString();

with

    var selectedTxt = info.selectionText()  //.trim()

Comment: After replacing that line no new tab opens at all. Is there anything else in the code I need to adjust following this?

Comment: I put the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75453918/firefox-extension-get-text-in-context-menu-javascript/75679390#75679390