# Firefox extension get text in context menu (javascript)

Tags: javascript, firefox, get, firefox-addon, selected

The first think i try was to get the selected text, but that is impossible in Firefox.Like this person [Firefox extension getSelection().toString() not getting the selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75420179/firefox-extension-getselection-tostring-not-getting-the-selected-text)
i read a lot other post and those code don't work in Firefox.

So i want to try another think. I have google search in context menu with already get selected text: [IMAGE for Google Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfedE.jpg)
And i want to get that text from the google search context menu.

The extension is page-translator. I fixed the "auto language" and want to add text translation. I am working in this almost 3 weeks and this is my last try.
Here is the complete extension:
https://www42.zippyshare.com/v/AS5RAMVR/file.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here for text selection

https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/blob/main/menu-demo/background.js

info.selectionText

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).